# How can I store multiple values upon the click of one button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a button to store the button value (id answer0, 'value2') as well as a drop down box selection (id answer1, 'value'. As the code is nothing is saving, though I have managed to save the button 'value2' in a previous attempt. Have been googling for 3 days to no avail. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
    $('.btn-answer').off('click').on('click', function(evt) {
        var answer0 = $(evt.target).attr("value2");
      //var answer1 = $("#answer1").val();
        var answer1 =$('#answer1 option:selected').text();
        var all_answers = {};
            all_answers['answer0'] = answer0;
            all_answers['answer1'] = answer1;
      if (typeof all_answers != 'undefined') {
        console.log(answer0);
        console.log(answer1);
        pybossa.saveTask(task.id, all_answers).done(function() {
                deferred.resolve();






<div>
            <select name="answer1" class = "btn-success btn-mini">
                <option value="none">Choose a Class</option>
                <option>Woodland and Scrub</option>
                        <option value="A1">Woodland</option>

                        ......
                        <option value="J5">Other Habitat</option>
                        </select>
                </div>




    <h1 id="question2"></h1> <!-- The question will be loaded here -->
    <h2><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> </h2>       
    <div id="answer0">             <!-- Start DIV for the submission buttons -->
        <!-- If the user clicks this button, the saved answer will be value2="Certai-->
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-answer" value2 ="a"><i class="icon icon-white icon-thumbs-up"></i> Certain</button>
        <!-- If the user clicks this button, the saved answer will be value2="Fairly Certain"-->
        <button class="btn btn-answer btn-warning" value2="b"><i class=""></i> Fairly Certain</button>
        <!-- If the user clicks this button, the saved answer will be value2="Fairly Certain"-->
        <button class="btn btn-answer btn-danger" value2="c"><i class="icon icon-white icon-thumbs-down"></i> Unsure</button>
    </div>
    <P></P>
    <!-- End of DIV for the submission buttons -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var selected_answer1 = $("#answer1").val();
```

I guess `$("#answer1")` is `input`, and with `$("#answer1").val("value")` you are trying to set its value. But you want to get its value.

To get value from drop down:

`$('#id_of_drop_down').val();` will return the value, not the text.

If you want text of selected `option`, use this:

`$('#id_of_drop_down option:selected').text();`.

Comment: Thanks :) the removing "value" means that the button bit (answer 0) now stores. Dropdown bit still being elusive though. How would I go about getting the value?

Comment: To get selected value of dropdown use the same way - `$('#id_of_drop_down').val();`.

Comment: hmm, that's what I am doing, problem must be elsewhere, thanks though!

Comment: My fault, sorry. `$('#id_of_drop_down').val();` will return the value, not the text. Do you want the text in `option`? If yes, then use this: `$('#id_of_drop_down option:selected').text();`.

Comment: Value or text will suffice. As stands the code is returning: {"info": {"answer0": "b"},   which relates to the button. Ideally it should return this alongside "answer1": "value??" relating to the drop down.

Comment: Have added the HTML for the drop down (with most of the options removed) & the button html. Thanks so much :)

Comment: it says name not id, forgot I changed that. Heavens I am a banana. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I found it. You dont have there id attribute. `<select name="answer1" class = "btn-success btn-mini">` - add there `id="answer1"`.